# React-native Error : Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I tried to create a project through `npx`, but an error occurred.

```
$ npx react-native init springtesting

error Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./springtesting/ios && pod install".
```

So I executed a sentence inside the ios folder in the project.

```
$ pod install

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: [!] /usr/local/bin/node -e console.log(require('@react-native-community/cli').bin);

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:983
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '@react-native-community/cli'
Require stack:
- /Users/myname/springtesting/ios/[eval]
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:980:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:862:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1040:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at [eval]:1:13
    at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:120:20)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:311:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> ([eval]-wrapper:10:26)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:94:25) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/User/myname/springtesting/ios/[eval]' ]
}
.

 #  from /Users/taehong/springtesting/ios/Podfile:42
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    use_native_modules!
 #  end
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

**Pod version**

```
$ pod --version
1.8.4
```

What's the problem?

And then i deleted the phrase 'use_native_modules' and it became normal.

Comment: Hi @hong developer have you found solution?

Comment: @Pavel A simple solution is to remove the phrase. i deleted the phrase 'use_native_modules'

Comment: I believe in this case you will be left with no native pods installed? Issue in my case was outdated version of "@react-native-community/cli".

Answer (score 0):

Your  error clearly states @react-native-community/cli is missing install it globally using

npm i -g @react-native-community/cli
If still it throws the same error update the cocoapods using

brew upgrade cocoapods

Answer (score 0):

run this:

```
xcode-select -p
```

if you do not get this path : `Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

then run this command

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```

create again new project
Good to go..

Answer (score 0):

> Your question shows that you didn't install
> **@react-native-community/cli**
>
> Solution 1 : run this command

```
npm i @react-native-community/cli
```

> update the cocoapods

Solution 2:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```